# How to determine whether a message is from a bot or a human user?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I am creating a bot that is simply sent message to a specific group.

### code

```
import telebot
import time

# BOT_TOKEN
bot = telebot.TeleBot('6332067145:AAElyMP_w69oR9********')

group_id = '-10017112******'

def send_msg():
    bot.send_message(group_id, "Hello")
    
# Start the bot
while True:
    send_msg()
    time.sleep(60)  # Sleep for 60 seconds (1 minute)
```

I create another bot that catch the msg & display it

code:

```
import re
import telebot

BOT_TOKEN = '6523213233:AAGzODrpeolUEc*************'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello! I'm MsgDetectorBot. I can detect Msg.")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def detect_messages(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, f"You sent: {message.text}")

bot.polling()
```

The first bot works properly, but the second bot can only find a message if it comes from a real person(real user). I search Google for the answer but can't find it(found but they said that it not possible). I would like to know if it is possible to determine if a message was sent by the bot. Then how?

Comment: Wouldn't also recognize its own message as a bot message and respond to it, hence endless loop?